# RUBY: Set variable to array element, regex thinks its an array

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string, match

I am trying to regex a character from a string that was assigned from an element of a scan result. I am trying to use match and it is complaining that the variable is an array. I am confused as to why "`trash`" is being seen as an array.

```
test = 'class="date">B=oddTu Q='
array = test.scan(/([A-Z])=/)
puts array
trash = array.last
trash.to_s
puts trash
if /Q/.match(trash)
  puts $1
end
```

And this is the results I'm seeing

```
C:\Ruby>scratch.rb
class="date">B=oddTu Q=
B
Q
Q
C:/Ruby/scratch.rb:14:in match: can't convert Array to String (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby/scratch.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

EDIT: scan returns an array of array, so by doing trash = array.last, trash then gets taken down one level to 1 array. Doing trash = trash[0] then takes it down to a string.

Comment: `array` is an array of arrays, so `trash` is actually an array. Use `p trash` to dump the variable and you'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boris points out, you're getting an array of arrays. It's because you have a group in your regex (a parenthesised expression). If you had several such groups, they would each correspond to an element in the returned arrays:

```
test.scan(/([A-Z])(=)/)
# => [["B", "="], ["Q", "="]]
```

In your case there's a few ways around this. You could simply `flatten` the array:

```
test.scan(/([A-Z])=/).flatten
# => ["B", "Q"]
```

or you could use a positive lookahead instead of grouping the bit you're interested in:

```
test.scan(/[A-Z](?==)/)
# => ["B", "Q"]
```

Unfortunately, since the bit you're not interested in is the `=` sign, it looks a bit weird with the lookahead syntax `(?=pattern)`, so the `flatten` option might be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `trash` is an array (of single element "Q"). You see it when you serialize.

See those two lines taken from my irb:

```
test.scan(/([A-Z])=/)
=> [["B"], ["Q"]]
```

The scan is returning array of arrays - for each match a value for each group.

You can not do matching on an array.